# Sort a list by alphabet but ignore special characters

Tags: c#, sorting

My Problem:
I have a list that I want to sort by sortname. That works very well. But i have sortnames with special chars at the begin. What can I do so that symbols are not observed?

Example of sortname with symbols: (alternative)Commerce Bank

my sortfunction:

```
cmembers.Sort(delegate (ChamberMembers x, ChamberMembers y)
                {
                    if (x.companysortName == null && y.companysortName == null) return 0;
                    else if (x.companysortName == null) return -1;
                    else if (y.companysortName == null) return 1;
                    else return x.companysortName.CompareTo(y.companysortName);
                });
```

The symbols may not be deleted!

Comment: Which characters are allowed in the beginning A-Z or numbers as well?

Comment: Using [CompareOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) (in your case `IgnoreSymbols`) should do the trick.

Comment: only begin with A-Z or a-z no numbers and special chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression and LINQ to order. You will need only two lines of code

```
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]");
        var result = input.OrderBy(x => reg.Replace(x, string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

**Full sample of code**

```
        var input = new List<string>();
        input.Add("(c");
        input.Add("*b");
        input.Add("_a");
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z]");
        var result = input.OrderBy(x => reg.Replace(x, string.Empty)).ToArray();
```

Comment: i like this idea. But i have a object not a sting. Do you have any ideas to solve this with an object? I mean i have a couple of strings in this Object and i wil sort the objects by this sortname

Comment: Can you give me the structure of your object?

Comment: here is the structure of my object: http://abload.de/img/structurepxs8r.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Just clean it up before comparison.

```
cmembers.Sort(delegate (ChamberMembers x, ChamberMembers y)
                {
                    if (x.companysortName == null && y.companysortName == null) return 0;
                    else if (x.companysortName == null) return -1;
                    else if (y.companysortName == null) return 1;
                    else return FilterSpecialChars(x.companysortName).CompareTo(FilterSpecialChars(y.companysortName));
                });

public static string FilterSpecialChars(string str)
{
    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, this is an example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ChamberMembers> lst = new List<ChamberMembers>();

        lst.Add(new ChamberMembers
        {
            companysortName = "b"
        });

        lst.Add(new ChamberMembers
        {
            companysortName = "z"
        });

        lst.Add(new ChamberMembers
        {
            companysortName = "e"
        });

        lst.Add(new ChamberMembers
        {
            companysortName = "a"
        });
        Console.WriteLine("\nBefore sort:");
        foreach (ChamberMembers ChamberMember in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ChamberMember.companysortName);
        }
        lst.Sort();
        Console.WriteLine("\nAfter sort:");
        foreach (ChamberMembers ChamberMember in lst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ChamberMember.companysortName);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }


}

public class ChamberMembers : IComparable<ChamberMembers>
{
    public string companysortName  { get; set; }


    public int CompareTo(ChamberMembers Chamber)
    {
        if (Chamber == null)
            return 1;
        else
               return string.Compare(this.companysortName, Chamber.companysortName, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols);
    }
}
```

Comment: While it's nice that you are implementing `IComparable` you example is missing the symbols/numbers the OP is struggling with.

Comment: You're right, I change the code so it could struggling with symbols and numbers