# C# Sorting string list with underscore and hyphen

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string>` with values `SK-Disbur` and `SK_Recon`. When I sort the list, what should be the output?

I am getting:

SK_Recon
SK-Disbur

I was expecting the other way around with Disbur before Recon, since hyphen comes before underscore.

Here is my code:

```
List<string> list=new List<string>();
list.Add("SK-Disbur");
list.Add("SK_Recon");
list.Sort();
for(int i=0;i <list.Count;i ++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Based on that code, I would expect the list to **not change**, since the `Sort()` method returns a new `IOrderedEnumerable` without actually modifying the list itself.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: `List<T>.Sort` does mutate the collection; its return type is `void`. You're probably thnking of `OrderBy`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by alphabet but ignore special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572699/sort-a-list-by-alphabet-but-ignore-special-characters)

Comment: Note that you can pass a `Comparison<T>` or an `IComparer<T>`, so you can manipulate how sort works

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing what you are doing currently?  Are you using [`Array.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0) or something else?

Answer (score 1):

By default list.Sort() uses the current culture's rules for sorting. That means each character is sorted using a linguistic sort (alphabetic sequence). You should use ordinal sorting so that its sorted by the binary value of each character. Try:
`list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);`

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't use ASCII, it uses Unicode UTF-16. When you perform a string sort, By default .NET are using the current culture's rules for sorting. In this case, those rules indicate that "_" comes before "-". You can get the result you expect by using the "ordinal" string comparer:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
    "SK-Disbur",
    "SK_Recon",
    "SK1",
    "SK2"
    };

    list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
```

you will get this result

```
SK-Disbur
SK1
SK2
SK_Recon
```

but if you use list.Sort() (by default) the result is very different

```
SK_Recon
SK-Disbur
SK1
SK2
```